# notifyDataSetChanged() not working with Filter

Tags: java, android, notifydatasetchanged

I am trying to set up a simple search on my listView. I am setting a custom adapter :

**MainActivity.java**

```
// Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
adapter = new AerodromesAdapter( this  , aerodromes);

// Binds the Adapter to the ListView
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

aerodromes is an ArrayList set global

```
 ArrayList<Aerodrome> aerodromes = new ArrayList<Aerodrome>();
```

In my ArrayAdapter AerodromeAdapter I have implemented the Filter the following way

**AerodromeAdapter.java**

```
ArrayList<Aerodrome> aerodromes;  // Displayed list
ArrayList<Aerodrome> aerodromesInit; // Original list

private Filter filter;
private Context ctx;

public AerodromesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Aerodrome> aerodromes) {
    super(context, R.layout.listview_item, aerodromes);
    this.ctx = context;
    this.aerodromes = aerodromes;
    this.aerodromesInit = this.aerodromes;

}

[...]

private class AerodromeFilter extends Filter {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        Log.v("VALUES", "publishResults");
        if (results.count == 0) {
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        } else {
            aerodromes = (ArrayList<Aerodrome>) results.values;

            Log.v("VALUES", String.valueOf(aerodromesInit.size()));

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        FilterResults results = new Filter.FilterResults();

        // perform your search here using the searchConstraint String.
        if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){

            results.values = aerodromesInit;
            results.count = aerodromesInit.size();
        }else{

            ArrayList<Aerodrome> filteredList = new ArrayList<Aerodrome>();
            for(Aerodrome j: aerodromesInit){
                if( j.code.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()) || j.name.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()) )
                    filteredList.add(j);
            }
            results.values = filteredList;
            results.count = filteredList.size();
        }

        Log.v("VALUES", "Recherche " + constraint.toString());
        Log.v("VALUES", "Trouvés " + results.count);

        return results;
    }
}
```

When typing in the search bar the performFiltering working perfectly and returns the right results but `notifyDataSetChanged();` does not seems to work at all.

I have read many notifyDataSetChanged(); threads problem but can't figure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you show method getCount() in your AerodromesAdapter?

Comment: I completely forgot that one !

I added it and everything works ! Thank you so much !
public int getCount() {
        return aerodromes.size();
    }

Comment: @Guitz: Can you answer your own question?